# monacaデバッガーのようなボタンは

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

monacaデバッガーにあるような、丸いボタン（タップするとにゅっと複数のボタンが出る）は自作アプリでも利用可能でしょうか。これを実装するのに参考になるようなサイト等ありませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

[このへん](http://codepen.io/nobitagit/full/ZYWVKw/)とか参考になりそうな気がします。
↑がぶっちぎりの一番人気でしたが、他にも[いろいろ](http://codepen.io/search?q=floating%20action&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false)ありました。

あとはGoogleのガイドラインとかですかね。
[Buttons: Floating Action Button](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#)